# Can I use exotic materials to make armor?

Tags: adnd-2e, crafting

Can I use other materials for making armor instead of metal, bone, wood or leather? Specifically, can I use spider exo-skeleton? If so, what are the rules and cost?

Comment: Yes, but it's not specifically spelled out. Check out the answer to this question: http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/10952/are-there-rules-for-skinning-animals-and-making-leather-armor-with-the-hide